# Angular.io Global Page Load event Application wide Applicable to All components

Tags: angular

In angular application, is it possible to define a global `Page Load` event application wide, which is applicable to all the components?

Background:
I have a angular application having 50 components. Each component has it's dedicated url. But all the components are independent and do not extend a common parent base component. I am tasked to add some analytics logic on each page/component visit. I was wondering if there is a way, we can write one page load event application wide, which is applicable to all the components. So that instead of modifying 50 components, is it possible to add the event application wide, and declare it as default.

Comment: You could write a service that all components use and call a method to record your activity when the component's `ngOnInit()` fires, or your components could extend a base class to encapsulate the service. Basing the event on the router is also possible, but you might have to maintain an array of the routes to record if you don't want all of the NavigationEnd events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define a global page load event in an Angular application. You can use the Angular Router to listen for the navigation events and trigger your analytics logic.

In your `app.module.ts` file, you can subscribe to the NavigationEnd event of the Router and execute your analytics code. Here's an example:

```js
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(event => {
        // your analytics logic here
        console.log('Page loaded: ', event.url);
      });
  }
}
```

If you need any additional logic (if you external component load any data from database) you can use Events, too.

Comment: That's working right away! Great